# Angular-CLI and css..

Tags: css, angular-cli

I'm trying to use an external css resource (Salesforce's Lightning Design System) in an Angular2 app i'm building.

I've installed it with bower and have got the 'styles' entry in angular-cli.json to recognise the correct css file.

However, there are icons and fonts associated with this package as well that I want to use. The build process seems to recognise what fonts i need as i can see these in the dist directory, but i don't know how to get the icons referenced in there at all?

The icons, for example, are called like:

```
<use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevrondown"></use>
```

However, I don't know how to setup a link to get to that /assets directory. Is this done in the angular-cli.json file also? That wouldn't be styles - so i'm curious where it would go??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i figured out one way to do it - although i'm not sure it's the right way..

I used express to map to the directory i need..

line in app.js

```
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/'))
```

then updated the html line to:

```
<use xlink:href="/css/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevrondown"></use>
```

all is good.. this doesn't feel like it's the best way to do it however.. i'm still VERY much open to suggestions!